# Plutus playground not starting with Interpreter error after running :set in GHCI

Tags: plutus-playground

```
plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: InterpreterError (CompilationErrors [CompilationError {filename = "\n/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-1626f2e537d27294/Main.hs", row = 2, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not load module \8216Playground.Contract\8217","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216playground-common-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package playground-common\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216playground-common-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package playground-common\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","2 | import Playground.Contract","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-1626f2e537d27294/Main.hs", row = 3, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not load module \8216Plutus.Contract\8217","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-contract-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-contract\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-contract-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-contract\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","3 | import Plutus.Contract","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-1626f2e537d27294/Main.hs", row = 4, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not load module \8216PlutusTx.Prelude\8217","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-tx-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-tx\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    It is a member of the hidden package \8216plutus-tx-0.1.0.0\8217.","    You can run \8216:set -package plutus-tx\8217 to expose it.","    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","4 | import PlutusTx.Prelude","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]}]))
```

[image]

I am getting an Interpreter error when trying to start the playground. It happened after I ran `:set -package plutus-ledger` in ghci. How can I reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by deleting path `~/.ghc/X86_.../environments/default`. It was loading this profile by default in ghci